# How to insert a new element into a ordered list and shift all other objects in Java?

Tags: java, list

Suppose I have this simple class:

```
public class User implements Comparable<User> {

  private String name;
  private Integer order;

  public User(String name, Integer order) {
    this.name = name;
    this.order = order;
  }

  //...Getters and Setters ommited
  
  @Override
  public int compareTo(User user) {
    return this.order.compareTo(user.getOrder());
  }
}
```

Just two attributes, the name of the user and the order. This attribute `order` will be used to know the position of the user inside a list. Then, I will create an unordered `LinkedList()` of them:

```
private static List<User> unorderedList() {
    final List<User> users = new LinkedList<>();
    
    users.add(new User("Joe", 5));
    users.add(new User("John", 2));
    users.add(new User("Maria", 8));
    users.add(new User("Kevin", 7));
    users.add(new User("Sophia", 9));
    users.add(new User("James", 1));
    users.add(new User("Adrian", 3));
    
    return users;
}
```

Now, I need to create and insert a new `User` in my list.

```
User u = new User("David", 2);
```

But, before I call the `add()` method, I have to do somethings.

I have to order this list (that's why I implemented `Comparable` on User class) and I have to update the attribute `order` to be sequential. So when I insert my new User in List, I need to have a final result like this:

```
1 - James    // No Change
2 - David    // New user inserted
3 - John     // Was order 2, become 3
4 - Adrian   // Was order 3, become 4
5 - Joe      // No Change
6 - Kevin    // There was no 6. Kevin was 7 so he become 6
7 - Maria    // Was 8
8 - Sophia - // Was 9
```

**EDIT 1: What I tried**

I tried to loop the list and compare the users order in list with new users order. The newUser have priority in position inside list.

```
final List<User> unorderedUsers = MainApp.unorderedList();
final AtomicInteger currentOrder = new AtomicInteger(1);
final User newUser = new User("David", 2);
Collections.sort(unorderedUsers);

unorderedUsers.forEach(user -> {
    if (user.getOrder().equals(newUser.getOrder())) {
        user.setOrder(user.getOrder() + 1);
    } else {
        user.setOrder(currentOrder.get());
    }

    currentOrder.incrementAndGet();
});

unorderedUsers.add(newUser);
Collections.sort(unorderedUsers);
System.out.println(String.format("Ordered with new User List -> %s", unorderedUsers));
```

However, the new user order is getting duplicated. I'm still trying to solve how to do a new sequential order. The result of my code is:

```
'James', order=1
'David', order=2
'John', order=3
'Adrian', order=3
'Joe', order=4
'Kevin', order=5
'Maria', order=6
'Sophia', order=7
```

**EDIT 2 - Possible Found Solution**
I don't know if this solution covers all scenarios, but I separate in two steps. I know it's a bit expensive, but it's what I got.

```
private void insertNewUser(final List <User> usersList, final User newUser) {
  final AtomicBoolean canShift = new AtomicBoolean(false);
  usersList.forEach(user ->{
    if (user.getOrder().equals(newUser.getOrder()) || canShift.get()) {
      user.shiftOrder();
      canShift.set(true);
    }
  });

  usersList.add(newUser);
  Collections.sort(usersList);
}

private void organizeOrder(final List <User> usersList) {
  final AtomicInteger currentOrder = new AtomicInteger(1);
  usersList.forEach(user -> user.setOrder(currentOrder.getAndIncrement()));
}
```

Then just call:

```
this.insertNewUser(...)
this.organizeOrder(...)
```

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve that ? SO is not a coding service, but it does help those who tried

Comment: If I may ask, why is the `order` an attribute of a `User`?

Comment: @azro added I've tried so far. I'm still trying

Comment: @MCEmperor this is an example. However, my client wants to do a manual ordering of the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to implement the `Comparable` interface. You can sort using a `Comparator`:

```java
users.addFirst(newUser);
// We're using addFirst here, because we want to make sure
// that the new user comes BEFORE possible users with the
// same order

AtomicInteger inc = new AtomicInteger();
users.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getOrder))
    .map(user -> {
        user.setOrder(inc.incrementAndGet());
        return user;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList();
```

In the above code, this is what happens: first, an `AtomicInteger` is created, which helps us to provide the users with new order numbers. Then, we sort the stream by the sequence number of the `User`. Then, we get a new sequence number from the `AtomicInteger`, and we set the `order` property with this number. Finally, we collect this into a list.

---

`addFirst()` makes sure that the new user is added at the beginning of the list. This is because in the finally sorted list, we want the new user to appear *before* any other user with the same order. Because the sorting is a *[stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)*, elements with equal sequence numbers appear in the same order as the unsorted stream.

As an alternative, instead of `addFirst()`, you could use

```
newUser.setOrder(newUser.getOrder() - 1);
users.add(newUser);
```

instead.

Comment: I tried your solution, but when I pass "David" with order 2, David ends up in position 3. He should be 2 and "John" 3.

Comment: @humungs Even with `addFirst` instead of `add`?

Comment: That's it! The `addFirst()` is necessary. I used `add()` of  `List`. So, your solution worked and I think this is a lot more elegant than my solution. Thanks.

Comment: @humungs Don't forget to accept the answer, if this is what you was looking for.

Comment: I was just making some unit testing to make sure I cover all scenarios. Thanks! Answer accepted!

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating Users having order higher than order (2) of new user. Sorting does not update your objects value. You can try that.

```
Collections.sort(users);
users.add( newUser.getOrder()-1 , newUser );
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(1);
users.forEach(
   user ->  user.setOrder( index.getAndIncrement() )
);
```